# where clause using IN query issue

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to implement check boxes to turn "types" of Services from the column ServiceType on and off. I am using this example here as a guide, but I am not showing any points on the map. I believe the problem arises while generating the where clause for the check boxes. I am using this example here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/in , but I am thoroughly confused and don't have the slightest idea what their column name is which they are querying among the numerous deviations of stores which I know some are arrays and others variables.

Here is my where clause(at the risk of embarrassing myself):

```
function generateWhere() {
    var filter = [];
    var serviceTypes = document.getElementsByName('ServiceType');
    for (var i = 0, serviceType; serviceType1 = serviceTypes[i]; i++) {
      if (serviceType1.checked) {
        var serviceType2 = serviceType1.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
        filter.push("'" + serviceType2 + "'");
      }
    }
    var where = '';
    if (filter.length) {
      where = "'ServiceType' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
    }
    return where;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the ID of your table?

Comment: This looks like the same question in the Fusion Tables Users Group (with more details): https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/944b0dce33f18056#

Answer (score 0):

from:
https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/944b0dce33f18056#

You have a typo (or an error) in your "checkboxes.html" 
This line:

```
var serviceTypes = document.getElementsByName('ServiceType');
```

has:

```
var serviceTypes = document.getElementsByName('ServiceType1');
```

and all the additional listeners for checkboxes that don't exist, break things.
When I change it back to the code you posted, it works for me:

http://www.geocodezip.com//Figueroa_Johnathan_checkboxes.html